# What is the difference between RPDO and TPDO?

Tags: embedded, can-bus, identification, canopen

deviceA: nodeID: 1
deviceB: nodeID: 2

Device **A sends** an **TPDO 181**, so **B gets** an **RPDO 181**.
Device **B sends** an **TPDO 182**, so **A gets** an **RPDO 182**.

There is an address range for RPDOs, for example 200 + ID. If A sends data it will be an TPDO.

**When will a CAN frame for example with 200 + 1 ID appear on the bus?**

As I see it all nodes transmit TPDOs so RPDOs can't appear on the bus. But it's not clear for me. If you can please provide some concrete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CANopen is not "plug & play", but it is almost ridiculously flexible in terms of features available.

In order to establish communication, you need to change the COBID either of the transmitters TPDOs or of the receivers RPDOs.

It is up to the system designer to decide where it would be most convenient to change the COBIDs. Suppose for example that you have a control system with a PLC sending out messages which in turn controls x number of standard I/O modules. All nodes have a standard factory mapping as specified by CANopen.

Since the system designer knows that all I/O modules have standardized identifiers for all RPDOs, depending on their node id, it might be more convenient to just change the PLC's TPDO COBID and leave the others with their factory setting - meaning you only need to change at once place.

Alternatively, perhaps the PLC will configure all COBIDs of the I/O modules during start-up through SDO access. In that case maybe it's more convenient to keep the PLCs TPDO COBIDs as defaults, but to change the slave's RPDO COBIDs. This would also allow multiple slaves to listen to the same TPDO simultaneously.

There's no obvious right or wrong, or even a standard implementation. Every CAN (open) bus implementation is unique and someone needs to take system level decisions about everything happening at that specific bus. Timing and identifier priorities is a big part of this - for example higher priority messages should be given lower identifiers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You mentioned that multiple slaves can listen to the sema TPDO, if the same COB-ID is set. But the second part of the COB-ID is the nodID, which shall be unique for each slave. So for example master (nodeID: 0x0), slaves (nodeID: 0x1,  0x2, 0x3), how can each slave listen to RPDO1 of master? Which nodeID shall be setted in the TPDO?

Comment: @kitaprak Node id is only relevant for calculating the default COBID per PDO. But as explained in this answer, you need to change COBID either on the transmitter or the receiver side and as soon as you do, you lose the relation between node id and COBID.

Answer (score 2):

When you develop a device with a CANopen interface, you have to include all needed messages/signals in its interface.

A Device A will typically send (TPDOs or Tx) messages to inform others about its status (sensor values, current operation mode...). These have ID 0x180 + NodeID (resp. 280, 380, 480 + NodeID).

It must receive some messages (RPDOs or Rx) so it can be controlled (operation mode, brightness, speed... chosen by a user). These have ID 0x200 + NodeID (resp. 300, 400, 500 + NodeID).

Of course RPDOs have to be sent by some other devices. But since they exist only because of Device A, they are primarily identified as RPDOs for this device.

This standard avoids ID-conflicts between messages, granted NodeIDs are unique and you stick to max 4 RPDOs and 4 TPDOs per device.

Comment: Thanks for the answear, but it's still not 100% clear. 
If A has a RPDO 0x200 + NodeID, here (if I'm not wrong) the node ID is the producers node ID. So why can't node A have an TPDO 0x200 + 1? No node will send an RPDO to A with 0x200 + 1.
 Please correct me if I'm wriong.

Comment: I don't understand your question. By producer do you mean sender? For RPDOs, NodeID in `0x200 + NodeID` refers to the receiver's Node ID. It's a convention to send TPDOs in the 180-1FF (resp. 280-2FF...) range and RPDOs in the 200-27F.

Comment: Yes, for me producer is the sender.
I dont understand that, how can a message be a TPDO and RPDO at the same time. If A sends a TPD-o to B, whats the message ID? 0x181 or 0x202? 
"0x200 + NodeID refers to the receiver's Node ID" so A sends a message with the nodeID of B?
What confuses me is that the TPDO of A is the RPDO of B but different address ranges are defined.

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean. You have to see this from a design/architecture perspective. A concrete example would be AC with for example NodeID 0x19. You'd have Fan speed as TPDO and desired temperature as RPDO. So your head unit would send a PDO with ID 0x219 to set desired temperature. It doesn't make sense to define this message as a TPDO of the head unit since it is part of the AC interface.

Comment: I think I'm getting close, can you please provide me a more detailed example, with message IDs? I think is hard me to understand, because I have to write a study, but I haven't used CANOpen in practice yet. Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: Could you descibe a classical case for TPDO and RPDO with message IDs from a designer perspective?

Comment: Is something missing in the AC example? It makes sense to define messages from the perspective of the AC device, since if you replace it with another model (or remove it altogether), all PDOs are likely to be different. This will change the messages sent by the head unit as well but those PDO aren't primarily related to the head unit... I feel like I'm repeating myself but I don't really know how else I can explain it.

Comment: I do not fully understand the concept outlined. There is an AC (0x19) and a head unit (NodeID: for example: 0x10). What are the use cases in this example? 
Head unit sends desired temperature: 0x219. I dont't see use case for message: 0x180 + 10, 0x200 + 0x10, 0x180 + 0x19. I would really appreciate your clarification, because I'm stuck.

Comment: 0x180 + 10 and 0x200 + 0x10 might be used in another context (unrelated to AC): broadcasting or setting date/time if your central clock is in the head unit for instance. 0x180 + 0x19 might be current operation mode of the AC (cooling, only ventilation only...). It's about modularity and compatibility of your can interface in different contexts really. If think you're viewing it from a purely physical perspective (sent/received)

Comment: An automotive OEM might have to combine devices from different suppliers. In this case, having an exhaustive description of the can interface of all devices allows you to program your own devices accordingly. Sticking to the CANopen rules mentioned in my answer makes sure there are no conflicts in message IDs